# Scroll table from top to Bottom, then Back Up (and repeat)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a code that on button press runs autoscroll on a single table but I need an option to Scroll Page from Top to Bottom, then Back Up (and Repeat), please check the code of my autoscroll option and what should I change or insert to enable this option?

Please check this script table on this host to see working process:
 (just upload any SRT subtitles file and click button "auto scroll")
[Click Here to check it](http://macanovic.000webhostapp.com)

```
 ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);

 define('SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER', 0);
 define('SRT_STATE_TIME',      1);
 define('SRT_STATE_TEXT',      2);
 define('SRT_STATE_BLANK',     3);

 $lines   = file("uploads/".$file_name);

 $subs    = array();
 $state   = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;
 $subNum  = 0;
 $subText = '';
 $subTime = '';

 foreach($lines as $line) {
     switch($state) {
         case SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER:
             $subNum = trim($line);
             $state  = SRT_STATE_TIME;
             break;

         case SRT_STATE_TIME:
             $subTime = trim($line);
             $state   = SRT_STATE_TEXT;
             break;

         case SRT_STATE_TEXT:
             if (trim($line) == '') {
                 $sub = new stdClass;
                 $sub->number = $subNum;
                 list($sub->startTime, $sub->stopTime) = explode(' --> ', $subTime);
                 $sub->text   = $subText;
                 $subText     = '';
                 $state       = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;

                 $subs[]      = $sub;
             } else {
                 $subText .= $line;
             }
             break;
     }
 }

 if ($state == SRT_STATE_TEXT) {
     // if file was missing the trailing newlines, we'll be in this
     // state here.  Append the last read text and add the last sub.
     $sub->text = $subText;
     $subs[] = $sub;
 }
 ?>
document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'block';

function autoScroll() {
  window.scrollBy(0, 400)
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("table");
  smooth_scroll_to(objDiv, objDiv.scrollHeight, 15900);
}

var smooth_scroll_to = function(element, target, duration) {
  target = Math.round(target);
  duration = Math.round(duration);
  if (duration < 0) {
    return Promise.reject("bad duration");
  }
  if (duration === 0) {
    element.scrollTop = target;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  var start_time = Date.now();
  var end_time = start_time + duration;

  var start_top = element.scrollTop;
  var distance = target - start_top;

  var smooth_step = function(start, end, point) {
    if (point <= start) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (point >= end) {
      return 1;
    }
    var x = (point - start) / (end - start);
    return x * x * (3 - 2 * x);
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var previous_top = element.scrollTop;

    var scroll_frame = function() {
      if (element.scrollTop != previous_top) {
        reject("interrupted");
        return;
      }

      var now = Date.now();
      var point = smooth_step(start_time, end_time, now);
      var frameTop = Math.round(start_top + (distance * point));
      element.scrollTop = frameTop;

      if (now >= end_time) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      if (element.scrollTop === previous_top &&
        element.scrollTop !== frameTop) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }
      previous_top = element.scrollTop;

      setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
    }
    setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an alternative code:

```js
$(function() {
  var intvl;
  var tm = 15900;

  function scrollDownTo(p, ms, cb) {
    console.log("Scrolling Down to " + p + " in " + ms + " ms");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: p
    }, ms, cb);
  }

  function scrollUpTo(p, ms, cb) {
    console.log("Scrolling Up to " + p + " in " + ms + " ms");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: p
    }, ms, cb);
  }

  function autoScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 400)
    var objDiv = $("table");
    if (objDiv.data("dir") == undefined) {
      objDiv.data("dir", 1);
      objDiv.data("action", "none");
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(objDiv.offset().top);
    if (objDiv.data("dir") == 1) {
      objDiv.data("action", "scroll");
      var t = objDiv.offset().top;
      var b = objDiv.offset().top + objDiv.height();
      scrollDownTo(b, tm, function() {
        console.log("Scroll Down Complete.");
        scrollUpTo(t, tm, function() {
          objDiv.data("action", "none");
          console.log("Scroll Up Complete.");
        });
      });
    }
  }

  autoScroll();
  var c = 0;
  intvl = setInterval(function() {
    if ($("table").data("action") == "none") {
      autoScroll();
    }
    if (c++ >= 30) {
      clearInterval(intvl);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Harper</td>
    <td>congue@natoquepenatibus.ca</td>
    <td>Id Mollis LLC</td>
    <td>7335 Molestie Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Axel</td>
    <td>orci.luctus@atlacus.edu</td>
    <td>Hymenaeos Mauris Inc.</td>
    <td>787-1741 Nec Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Candace</td>
    <td>leo.Morbi.neque@Duis.edu</td>
    <td>At Ltd</td>
    <td>232-6504 Quis Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Diana</td>
    <td>eu.odio.tristique@Duisrisusodio.edu</td>
    <td>Nec Limited</td>
    <td>5691 Eu, Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daniel</td>
    <td>ante.bibendum.ullamcorper@Nuncut.net</td>
    <td>Turpis Egestas Corporation</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 970, 9130 Feugiat Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nissim</td>
    <td>pharetra@nuncestmollis.net</td>
    <td>Semper Limited</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 330, 8779 Ultricies Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Velma</td>
    <td>Cras@mollisduiin.net</td>
    <td>Hendrerit Neque In Ltd</td>
    <td>985-9826 Viverra. Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Denise</td>
    <td>vel.mauris.Integer@risusDonec.edu</td>
    <td>Vitae Posuere LLP</td>
    <td>696-1565 Tincidunt Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Geoffrey</td>
    <td>dolor@estNuncullamcorper.ca</td>
    <td>Hendrerit Neque In PC</td>
    <td>1862 Tempus St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sophia</td>
    <td>eleifend@estmollisnon.co.uk</td>
    <td>Id Ante Dictum LLP</td>
    <td>8063 Massa Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Talon</td>
    <td>eget.volutpat@sitamet.edu</td>
    <td>Tincidunt Donec Corp.</td>
    <td>Ap #958-6983 In, St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alma</td>
    <td>fermentum.arcu@tristiquenequevenenatis.co.uk</td>
    <td>Sagittis Lobortis Mauris Company</td>
    <td>999-6082 Eleifend St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yuli</td>
    <td>suscipit.nonummy.Fusce@Proinvelarcu.co.uk</td>
    <td>Ligula Aliquam Company</td>
    <td>8939 Molestie Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Susan</td>
    <td>Integer.in.magna@Uttinciduntvehicula.org</td>
    <td>Dictum Magna Incorporated</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 405, 3923 Eros Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rogan</td>
    <td>ut.pellentesque.eget@cursusnon.org</td>
    <td>Iaculis Corporation</td>
    <td>3745 Cursus Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Malcolm</td>
    <td>Donec@laciniaSed.edu</td>
    <td>Et Netus LLP</td>
    <td>8816 Fringilla St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Xena</td>
    <td>pede@scelerisquesed.net</td>
    <td>Congue A Aliquet Institute</td>
    <td>652-5287 Lectus, Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shaeleigh</td>
    <td>Curae@liberoDonec.co.uk</td>
    <td>Nullam Suscipit Limited</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 106, 3607 Dolor Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ori</td>
    <td>elit.Nulla.facilisi@variusorci.co.uk</td>
    <td>Nunc Sit Limited</td>
    <td>146-7683 Dolor Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wanda</td>
    <td>Mauris.nulla@magnaCras.edu</td>
    <td>Erat Corp.</td>
    <td>2267 Pellentesque St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nicholas</td>
    <td>egestas.a.dui@egetmetus.org</td>
    <td>Ipsum Curabitur Consequat Incorporated</td>
    <td>4770 Quam Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zenia</td>
    <td>Vestibulum@taciti.ca</td>
    <td>Elit Institute</td>
    <td>2747 Ac Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Georgia</td>
    <td>eleifend@acturpisegestas.edu</td>
    <td>Lorem Vehicula Incorporated</td>
    <td>436-3813 Nisl Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hop</td>
    <td>interdum.feugiat@consectetueradipiscing.com</td>
    <td>Nulla Incorporated</td>
    <td>6479 Cursus. St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Luke</td>
    <td>gravida.mauris@nonsollicitudin.com</td>
    <td>Nulla LLP</td>
    <td>165-3516 Porta Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Allegra</td>
    <td>elementum.lorem@anunc.ca</td>
    <td>Penatibus Et Magnis LLP</td>
    <td>719-2047 Sociis Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chantale</td>
    <td>turpis.Aliquam@quislectusNullam.com</td>
    <td>Justo Praesent Luctus Corp.</td>
    <td>Ap #834-7566 Erat Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mira</td>
    <td>malesuada@a.com</td>
    <td>Arcu LLP</td>
    <td>7169 Mi Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nyssa</td>
    <td>Aenean@convallis.ca</td>
    <td>Varius Nam Porttitor Institute</td>
    <td>838-5375 Velit St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mona</td>
    <td>a.malesuada@purusDuis.net</td>
    <td>Quam Pellentesque Habitant Industries</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 649, 2025 Vulputate Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tiger</td>
    <td>nec.tempus.scelerisque@dapibus.com</td>
    <td>Vel Arcu Eu Foundation</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 689, 1544 Nec Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Latifah</td>
    <td>mi.ac.mattis@maurisidsapien.co.uk</td>
    <td>Sit Amet Luctus Incorporated</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 123, 6415 Diam. Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Raja</td>
    <td>Sed.congue.elit@eu.ca</td>
    <td>Orci Phasellus Dapibus Corporation</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 521, 8717 Ultrices Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hashim</td>
    <td>est.vitae@euelitNulla.edu</td>
    <td>Felis Inc.</td>
    <td>2451 Semper Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upton</td>
    <td>Morbi.neque.tellus@molestie.org</td>
    <td>Orci Donec Nibh Inc.</td>
    <td>647-1389 Metus Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dai</td>
    <td>ac@lectusrutrumurna.com</td>
    <td>Fusce Diam Nunc Company</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 311, 6508 Nulla. Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sopoline</td>
    <td>Nulla.dignissim@purusMaecenas.net</td>
    <td>Pede Blandit Corp.</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 316, 4463 Vestibulum St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brandon</td>
    <td>vestibulum.massa@sapien.com</td>
    <td>Non Dui Nec Corp.</td>
    <td>Ap #718-9013 Phasellus Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jeanette</td>
    <td>pretium.et@venenatisvelfaucibus.co.uk</td>
    <td>Suscipit Est Ac LLP</td>
    <td>9525 Enim, Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MacKenzie</td>
    <td>eget.nisi.dictum@iaculisodioNam.org</td>
    <td>Rutrum Eu PC</td>
    <td>547-9096 Velit Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>luctus@temporaugue.edu</td>
    <td>Sed Company</td>
    <td>710-8341 Urna. Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Clio</td>
    <td>vitae.risus@urnaUt.com</td>
    <td>Magna Nec Quam Consulting</td>
    <td>591-6993 Scelerisque Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keefe</td>
    <td>Nulla@enimEtiamgravida.org</td>
    <td>Suspendisse Corp.</td>
    <td>Ap #264-221 Amet St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Andrew</td>
    <td>metus.vitae@facilisis.net</td>
    <td>At Augue Ltd</td>
    <td>527-740 Blandit St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Duncan</td>
    <td>Donec.tempor.est@dignissimMaecenas.com</td>
    <td>Vitae PC</td>
    <td>646-1450 Lorem Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Abraham</td>
    <td>neque.Sed@necurnaet.ca</td>
    <td>Nibh Enim Gravida Foundation</td>
    <td>4673 Nunc St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Meredith</td>
    <td>arcu.Aliquam.ultrices@famesac.edu</td>
    <td>Elementum Sem PC</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 624, 8888 Augue Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Patience</td>
    <td>Aenean.euismod@fermentumrisusat.com</td>
    <td>Dapibus Gravida Aliquam Consulting</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 421, 2581 Id Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hoyt</td>
    <td>nisi.Cum.sociis@etnetus.edu</td>
    <td>Metus Sit Corp.</td>
    <td>Ap #767-2231 Sit Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haviva</td>
    <td>quis.massa@ligulaNullamenim.co.uk</td>
    <td>Auctor Ullamcorper Nisl Corporation</td>
    <td>Ap #637-942 Nullam Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rigel</td>
    <td>dolor.Donec@necdiam.org</td>
    <td>Et Libero Proin Inc.</td>
    <td>3517 Ullamcorper. Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Len</td>
    <td>nisi@inhendreritconsectetuer.org</td>
    <td>Nisl Nulla Eu Consulting</td>
    <td>298-1354 Ullamcorper, Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>quis.arcu.vel@dapibusrutrumjusto.com</td>
    <td>Eu Enim Incorporated</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 693, 7557 Aenean Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boris</td>
    <td>purus.Duis@acurna.edu</td>
    <td>Nunc In At Corp.</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 550, 1909 Tristique Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Abigail</td>
    <td>bibendum.ullamcorper@metusfacilisislorem.edu</td>
    <td>Eu LLP</td>
    <td>713-4207 Sed St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unity</td>
    <td>malesuada.malesuada@risus.co.uk</td>
    <td>Morbi LLC</td>
    <td>572-4709 Ipsum Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yuli</td>
    <td>adipiscing.lacus.Ut@nequeNullam.ca</td>
    <td>Integer Mollis LLP</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 410, 8948 Nunc. St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brittany</td>
    <td>tristique@egestaslacinia.edu</td>
    <td>Libero Associates</td>
    <td>399-9226 Ac St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Risa</td>
    <td>nunc.nulla@consectetueradipiscingelit.co.uk</td>
    <td>Nam Inc.</td>
    <td>198-1208 Commodo Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kieran</td>
    <td>et.magnis@dolor.org</td>
    <td>Leo Cras Foundation</td>
    <td>705-349 Orci Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Donovan</td>
    <td>turpis.vitae.purus@infaucibus.ca</td>
    <td>Montes Nascetur Ridiculus Ltd</td>
    <td>3781 Risus. St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leilani</td>
    <td>sit.amet.risus@commodo.ca</td>
    <td>Vitae Corp.</td>
    <td>231-5948 Cursus. Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sonya</td>
    <td>est.Mauris@velitAliquamnisl.ca</td>
    <td>Mauris Consulting</td>
    <td>Ap #668-8080 Nam Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hayes</td>
    <td>eget@luctus.ca</td>
    <td>Aliquam Company</td>
    <td>Ap #519-7064 Vel Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Erica</td>
    <td>erat.Vivamus.nisi@ligulaDonecluctus.com</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Associates</td>
    <td>Ap #702-8217 Erat Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>mattis@ipsum.com</td>
    <td>Sed Dolor Fusce PC</td>
    <td>327 Malesuada Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Christine</td>
    <td>vulputate.nisi.sem@Namnulla.ca</td>
    <td>Faucibus Leo In Industries</td>
    <td>4782 Diam. Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Katell</td>
    <td>Praesent@disparturientmontes.edu</td>
    <td>Consectetuer Adipiscing Elit PC</td>
    <td>8264 Curabitur Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zelenia</td>
    <td>Duis@nonfeugiat.com</td>
    <td>Nulla Donec Non Inc.</td>
    <td>993-9667 Semper Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jonah</td>
    <td>augue.eu.tellus@arcuetpede.org</td>
    <td>Gravida Sagittis Duis Industries</td>
    <td>476-6694 Pharetra Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lyle</td>
    <td>eu@ullamcorper.co.uk</td>
    <td>Diam Nunc Consulting</td>
    <td>Ap #671-9373 Ultrices, Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mannix</td>
    <td>Cras@magnisdis.com</td>
    <td>Ut Dolor Dapibus LLC</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 379, 7246 Rhoncus. Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leila</td>
    <td>senectus.et@idblandit.co.uk</td>
    <td>Sed Limited</td>
    <td>4394 Integer St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phelan</td>
    <td>ultrices.a@auctorodioa.net</td>
    <td>Aliquam PC</td>
    <td>3273 Nulla Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Velma</td>
    <td>sociis.natoque@Suspendissetristiqueneque.co.uk</td>
    <td>Ac Ipsum Consulting</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 437, 3652 Ullamcorper. Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ashely</td>
    <td>ac@leoelementumsem.com</td>
    <td>Enim Limited</td>
    <td>563-2520 Eu Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adria</td>
    <td>Cras.convallis.convallis@Integertinciduntaliquam.ca</td>
    <td>Nunc Laoreet Lectus LLP</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 632, 8503 Nam St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Herrod</td>
    <td>lorem@hendreritnequeIn.net</td>
    <td>Orci Phasellus Dapibus Associates</td>
    <td>848-1593 Mauris Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Todd</td>
    <td>tellus.imperdiet.non@arcuimperdietullamcorper.co.uk</td>
    <td>Dui Quis LLP</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 371, 5356 Cum St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rhona</td>
    <td>scelerisque.mollis.Phasellus@sapiengravidanon.edu</td>
    <td>Tortor Institute</td>
    <td>Ap #357-7299 Luctus. Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ali</td>
    <td>Fusce.dolor.quam@eu.com</td>
    <td>Adipiscing Non Luctus Industries</td>
    <td>Ap #185-4416 Donec Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fallon</td>
    <td>scelerisque@maurisutmi.net</td>
    <td>Dolor Tempus Non Inc.</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 881, 4626 Dolor Avenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keegan</td>
    <td>Praesent.interdum@laciniaorci.edu</td>
    <td>Quis Arcu Company</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 125, 1827 Erat, Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Irene</td>
    <td>consequat@tempus.co.uk</td>
    <td>Nulla Incorporated</td>
    <td>823-2595 Netus Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kato</td>
    <td>Aliquam.gravida.mauris@Sed.net</td>
    <td>Semper Pretium Neque Ltd</td>
    <td>7649 Nascetur Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Basia</td>
    <td>libero.est@sodalesMauris.co.uk</td>
    <td>Ultrices A Auctor Ltd</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 257, 5567 Tortor, St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Neil</td>
    <td>cursus.luctus.ipsum@temporarcu.net</td>
    <td>Tincidunt Tempus Inc.</td>
    <td>405-8028 Arcu Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kerry</td>
    <td>mattis.Integer@vitae.org</td>
    <td>Parturient Ltd</td>
    <td>933-3617 Morbi Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lamar</td>
    <td>ullamcorper.viverra@ipsum.net</td>
    <td>Ante Blandit Company</td>
    <td>473-9087 Auctor Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gretchen</td>
    <td>vel.arcu@sed.net</td>
    <td>Sed Congue LLC</td>
    <td>9862 Sed Road</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maile</td>
    <td>ullamcorper.eu@lectus.edu</td>
    <td>Morbi Vehicula Pellentesque Consulting</td>
    <td>620-2170 Egestas Av.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jolie</td>
    <td>Fusce.feugiat.Lorem@erosNam.ca</td>
    <td>Et Magnis Dis Inc.</td>
    <td>Ap #620-8133 Tristique Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Patience</td>
    <td>amet@hymenaeos.net</td>
    <td>Pede Sagittis Augue Corp.</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 506, 9817 Tempus Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zeus</td>
    <td>enim@nec.org</td>
    <td>Nulla Cras Eu Ltd</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 866, 3866 Tellus Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Giselle</td>
    <td>sit.amet.dapibus@cursusin.net</td>
    <td>Suspendisse LLC</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 891, 1249 Velit St.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Uta</td>
    <td>fames.ac@amet.co.uk</td>
    <td>Ultricies Ltd</td>
    <td>460-8906 Molestie Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orlando</td>
    <td>In.ornare.sagittis@nec.edu</td>
    <td>Imperdiet Erat Foundation</td>
    <td>997-4156 Mauris Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demetrius</td>
    <td>et@idante.edu</td>
    <td>Neque Non Corporation</td>
    <td>822-8359 Amet Ave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Allegra</td>
    <td>lorem.semper@aliquet.co.uk</td>
    <td>Nunc Quisque Limited</td>
    <td>Ap #509-6316 Auctor Rd.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adrienne</td>
    <td>metus.In@pellentesquemassa.ca</td>
    <td>Augue Ut Lacus Industries</td>
    <td>P.O. Box 168, 5359 Dolor Rd.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This makes use of `.animate()` to scroll down and then cascade a scroll up. It then uses setInterval to restart the job for a specific number of times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like it Twisty, but how can I integrate this on my website script, also I need auto scroll function on button press . Check my script please: macanovic.000webhostapp.com

Comment: @Edgar I can't tell you how to implement it in your site. It looks like you're using PHP to generate content. I would advise creating a template for JS or your Header. If you want to assign `autoScroll()` to a button click, you just need to include it in the `click` event callback. If you want more help, see my initial comment on you post.

Comment: thank you Twisty, I will try to add your code to my script.

Comment: @Edgar good! Give it a try. If you run into problems, you can always search more or post another question.

Comment: @Edgar if this has answered your question, you will want to Mark it. If you like it, you can also upvote it.